# Bound for polar equations.

Tags: calculus

When I wish to find the area of a polar equation such as $r=2-2\cos\theta$, I need to compute
$$\frac12\int_\alpha^{\beta}r^2.$$
However, I am confused as to how to determine $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I know that they are the "starting angle" and "ending angle", but how exactly do we define them? Are they the values of $\theta$ when $r=0$?

[image: graph of the curve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually simplifies calculations to choose α and β such that $r=0$, but it is not necessary. The important part is that $\beta=2\pi+\alpha$, that is, the "starting angle" is $2\pi$ (one full rotation) less than the "ending angle." In this case, I would choose $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=2\pi$, but it really doesn't matter. This is because when you start at a given angle and add $2\pi$, you end back up at the same angle having swept out the area of the graph. If you want evidence of this, type "$\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{a+2\pi}\left(\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)^{2}d\theta$" into desmos and add a slider for a. You can change the input however you like. As you change a, the answer doesn't change.
In this case, there is also a neat trick that you can do. The area in the upper 2 quadrants is the same as in the lower 2. Because of this, if you find the area of one, you find the area of the other. That is, the area of the top half *2 is the whole area. Because of this, if we choose values of $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=\pi$, this will be half of the final answer. We can multiply the integral by 2 (canceling the $1/2$ at the front) to get that the whole area is equal to $\int_0^\pi (2-2\cos(\theta))^2d\theta$. In general, you will be either using $\alpha$ and $\beta$ values that the problem provides, $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=2\pi$, or leveraging symmetry in some way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).